# After updating EE from 1.6.8 to 2.7.3 Playa won't update the exp_playa_relationships table

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic, ee2-upgrades, updating

I've successfully updated ExpressionEngine to 2.7.3 but after I try to install the updated version of Playa (4.4.5) I continually get this error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /system/third_party/playa/ft.playa.php on line 314

I've tried increasing the max_execution_time to a longer duration of time, reimporting the database and running again but same error.

It looks like all of my entries are still intact in the exp_relationships table, they just aren't getting moved into the exp_playa_relationships table.

The exp_relationships table has 93,553 rows in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a line set_time_limit(30) in /system/third_party/playa/ft.playa.php that was overriding the set_time_limit I had set in MAMPs PHP settings. The line was:

> set_time_limit(30)

After increasing the default from (30) Playa was able to update the old table to the new exp_playa_relationships table.